# when taken 5 root of big number gives wrong answere in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I take the 5 root of a big number, js gives me a wrong answer

```js
var pow = 5;
var A = 133;
var B = 110;
var C = 84;
var D = 27;
var E;

E = Math.pow((Math.pow(A, pow) + Math.pow(B, pow) + Math.pow(C, pow) + Math.pow(D, pow)), 1/pow);

console.log(E)
```

This should give 144 but gives 144.00000000000003
5 root of 61917364224 = 144

Comment: This is normal because of floating point precision. Only thing you can do is round it.

Comment: Here is a good resource on this topic https://floating-point-gui.de/basic/